# jQuery: Select <classname1> but filter out <classname2>

Tags: jquery

jQuery Validation plugin can generate two types of labels, one with class="error" and the other has class="error valid".

I have the following code to detect the existence of labels with class="error":

```
($form.find("label.error").not($form.find("label.valid")).length == 0);
```

Is there any other better (ie. more optimized) way doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this `$('div.error:not(.valid').css('background-color', 'red');` as seen in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/cMHVx/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough to know only information about '.error' class name,

```
($form.find("label.error").length == 0);
```

or

```
(!$form.find("label.error").length);
```

Comment: The problem with using just $form.find("label.error") is that labels with class="error valid" also got picked up. class="error valid" means the labels belong to both "error" and "valid" classes.